# Express plotly Chloropeth not showing map

Tags: python, plotly

I am having problem with showing chloropeth image.

This my code:

```
print(pred_data)
      ratings  score state     price_1
0         0.0      0    AL   11.018611
1         0.0      0   NaN         NaN
2         0.0      0    WY   10.302375
3         0.0      0    WI    9.870076
4         0.0      0    MN    8.648731
...       ...    ...   ...         ...
2395      5.5    450    VT -146.422781
2396      5.5    450    UT    3.709167
2397      5.5    450    PR  287.116306
2398      5.5    450    TX   -8.880539
2399      5.5    450    AR  372.928638

[2400 rows x 4 columns]

import plotly_express as px
fig = px.choropleth(pred_data,
                    locations='state', 
                    locationmode="USA-states", 
                    scope="usa",
                    color='price_1',
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis_r", 
                    
                    )
fig.show()
```

Nothing shows up.

I have been trying to solve this.

Comment: I believe the `NaN` data is affected, so please delete the `NaN` row and run. By the way, I created similar data and the graph was created correctly.